# Firebase dont write

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a function that deletes matches from users if the match is not played after 15 minutes. if the user that create the match add coins to the match, the function retrieves that coins to the user profile.
here is the code

```
function deleteMatch(key,user,bet){

  MatchesRef.child(key).remove();
  UsersRef.child(user).once('value').then(userSnapshot => {
    const credits = userSnapshot.val().credits || 0;
    return UsersRef.child(user).child('credits').set(credits + parseInt(bet, 10));
  })
}
```

The problem is if the function recieve in the parameters a user that create 2 matchs in the same minute, only add 1 coin.
User1 have 9 coins and user2 have 8 coins.

Example parameters: match1(key1, user1, 1), match2(key2,user2,1)

with this parameters the code work, and now user1 have 10 coins and user2 have 9.

But with differente paramenters

user1 have 9 coins, user2 have 8 coins.

Example parameters with problems: 
match1(key1,user1,1), match2(key2,user2,1) match3(key3,user1,1).

With this the code read all the matches, but after the code the user1 have 10 coins, and user 2 have 9 coins.

The code is not giving 2 coins, 1 for every match that user1 create.

I think this is because firebase are trying to write to the user node 2 times at once. But no idea how to solve

The code that starts the action

```
module.exports = () =>
  MatchesRef.once('value').then(snap => {
    const now = new Date().getTime();
    const records = [];
    snap.forEach(row => {
      const { date, hour, adversary1, bet } = row.val();
      console.log("el adversario es "+ adversary1);
      if (!date || !hour) return;
      const [day, month] = date.split('/').map(p => parseInt(p, 10));
      const [h, min] = hour.split(':').map(p => parseInt(p, 10));
      const scheduledTime = (new Date((new Date()).getFullYear(), month - 1, day, h, min, 0, 0))
          .getTime() + expireMinutes * 60 * 1000;
      if (scheduledTime <= now) {

          records.push({ key: row.key, user: adversary1, bet });

          deleteMatch(row.key,adversary1,bet);
        //records.map(({key,user,bet}) => deleteMatch({key,user, bet}))
      }
    });
    return Promise.all(
     // records.map(({key, user, bet}) => expireMatch(key, user, bet))
    );
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was firebase try to write 2 times at the same location and to avoid this problem I implement transactions, who guarantee that firebase wait until the previous write was finished.

```
UsersRef.child(user).child('credits').transaction(function(currentCredits){
         console.log(currentCredits);
          return currentCredits + parseInt(bet, 10);
        })
```